# can we change the name of the jar called into another tar,using assembly plugin when both jar pom and tar pom are under the same parent pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

i need to generate a jar using a pom and send this jar to another tar files,which are created using another pom, under the same parent pom.i achieved this using the maven-assembly plugin and using  of assembly.xml  file.But while packing the jar into the tar,the name of the final name of the jar is appearing along with the version.is there any way by which i can keep it to my required name,after the jar is generated into the tar.

the tar pom assembly plugin used:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>First</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>${project.basedir}/src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>First</finalName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.application</groupId>
        <artifactId>jarName</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

assembly.xml file

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>com.application.jarName:jar</include>
        </includes>          
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

in jar, i gave version as 0.0.1

required jar name - "jarName"
    ::::::::
appearing jar name:"jarName-0.0.1"

when i execute the jar pom alone, any name can be given as final name using the  tag in the jar plugin, but when i execute it using tar-pom, i'm unable to get the required name to my jar after generating in the Tar.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your requirement: `required jar name :jarName appearing jar name:jarName-0.0.1` ?

Comment: This jar should be generated in another place(a tar), where the name of the jar should be what i want to give.(i.e; i want to remove the version from name)

Comment: In the `dependencySet` you can define the file name mapping see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet

Comment: i used the <outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>   Tag